# German Umlaut in R markdown header for GitHub document (table of content)

Tags: r, github, rstudio, knitr, pandoc

I am new to R, RMarkdown and GitHub. Is there a way to write a header with German Umlaut in RMarkdown, so that it generates a correct link for a GitHub document?

I am using RStudio and I have tried:

```
# Datensätze
# Datens&auml;tze
# [Datens&auml;tze](Datens&auml;tze)
```

After using knitr in RStudio the links do work. But after pushing it to the remote repo in GitHub they do not work anymore.

I am using:

```
output: 
    github_document:
            toc: yes
            toc_depth: 3
```

Maybe there are some commands in knitr or pandoc-extensions?

*** Here follows a reproducible example

````
---
title: "Link test"
output:
    github_document:
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 2
    html_preview: false
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Some text 

## Datensätze

Some text
````

The above code produces in my installation the following md file. The automatically produced TOC `-   [Datensätze](#datensatze)` does not link to my header `Datensätze` when I knitr the document and transfer the md file via git to GitHub.

```
Link test
================

-   [Datensätze](#datensatze)

Some text

Datensätze
----------

Some text
```

**After a discussion with RStudio they filed an issue on this problem. In the meanwhile, the problem is solved. Headers with German umlaute in the table of content refer correctly to the headers in the text!**

Comment: What encoding are you using when saving the file? You might try forcing UTF-8 encoding. For what it's worth, I wasn't able to reproduce the issue -- links of the form e.g. `umlaut.md#datensätze` appear to work fine on a test Markdown document.

Comment: RStudio and OS Sierra uses UTF-8. Umlaut does **display** correctly but whenever I use them in a header, the automatically generated link does not work. It seems to me that knitr/pandoc converts correctly. In the Viewer panel inside RStudio the link works, but pushing the file to GitHub destroys it.The result in the table of content is `[Datensätze](#datensatze)`.

Comment: Can you post a a full reproducible example? That is, an R Markdown document that, when rendered, produces a Markdown document with these broken links?

Comment: What *should* be in the TOC seems to be `[Datensätze](#datensätze)`. See [here](https://github.com/ClaudiusL/test/blob/master/test.md) for a demo. But I'm not sure which package is responsible for this. Maybe `rmarkdown` or `pandoc`. Probably not `knitr`.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful! I updated all packages and started from scratch but didn't succeed yet. I will continue investigating the issue. Now at least I know that it should work.

Comment: In the meanwhile, I had a discussion with RStudio and they filed an issue on this problem in [rmarkdown](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1048)